# jQuery get class name from highlighted text

Tags: jquery, text, focus

There is a button and a contendeditable div.

In the div are some text. The selected or highlighted text is in a span with a class which is highlighted.

edit:
If i click a button i need the name of the span class ('saymyname') because this is the highlighted.

for example:
HTML:

```
<button>click</button>
<div contenteditable="true">
   A none highlighted text and now
   <span class='saymyname'>i'm highlighted</span>
   more text
   <span class='im_temporary_not_important'>more text</span>
</div>
```

How can i handle it with jQuery?

```
$(button).click(function (){
   ?
});
```

Comment: Do you need all class of span  inside the  div?

Comment: This is not a simple request. How will you deal with selections which cover multiple parts of several different elements? My suggestion would be to look at the [Rangy plugin](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) as it should at least help with getting the elements which contain the text selection.

Comment: only the the one which is highlighted ('saymyname')

Comment: no ideas or it is not possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```js
$("button").click(function (){
  $("#content span").each(function(){
      $(".classNames").append($(this).attr("class")+"<br>");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
<div contenteditable="true" id="content">
   A none highlighted text and now
   <span class='saymyname'>i'm highlighted</span>
   more text
   <span class='im_temporary_not_important'>more text</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="classNames">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Divyesh Savaliya. But i need only the one how is Highlighted (saymyname) by cursor